# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction Passing Wrong Parameter Value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0. I have an ActionResult which receives a form post with a value from a drop down list. It then redirects to an ActionResult, passing the value as a parameter. Here are my 2 ActionResult methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FindPromo()
{
    var promoId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlPromotion"]);
    return RedirectToAction("GetPromo", new { id= promoId });
}

public ActionResult GetPromo(int id)
{

    if (promoId > 0)
    {
        var model = GetModel(id);

        if (model.Promo != null)
        {
            return View("Promo", GetModel(id));
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("NotFound");
}
```

When I debug this, the value from the drop down list is pulled correctly from my form, but on the redirect, a different value from a previous request comes through as the promoId value on the GetPromo method. This happens even if I I totally close out of the page and reload it, almost as if it's cached somewhere. I know this is something simple, but I've never run across this before.

EDIT:

I changed the parameter names from promoId to id, and also updated my routing table. I've updated my code sample above, and here are my routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute("GetPromo", "{controller}/GetPromo/{id}",
        new { controller = "Promo", action = "GetPromo" });

    routes.MapRoute("FindPromo", "{controller}/FindPromo/{id}",
        new { controller = "Promo", action = "FindPromo" });
```

I'm still getting the same results with the parameters, however.

Comment: did you find out what was actually causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the default route setting: {controller}/{action}/{id}?
Also, are those your only routes? The routes are evaluated in sequence so a previous route can override one below if it matches. 
Phil Haack published a route debugger in his blog at [haacked.com](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

You can also play with: RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(), passing the ViewContext.RequestContext and a RouteValueDictionary and see the resulting Url.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is related to your routing set up.  Try renaming `promoId` to `id` and updating your route values.  If that doesn't work, could you update your post with your routes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
return RedirectToAction("GetPromo", new { id = promoId.ToString() });
```

I think we ran on a similar problem and that solved the issue.

If not, you can do this:

```
var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
dict.Add("id", promoId);

return RedirectToAction("GetPromo", dict);
```

And as a recommendation, you shouldn't use Convert.ToInt32, use int.Parse or int.TryParse instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your IOC container isn't registering your controllers as singletons. I'm using Windsor and the default lifestyle type is singleton and this was causing the "caching" behaviour. See: [ASP.NET MVC - Controller parameter not being gathered from form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879608/asp-net-mvc-controller-parameter-not-being-gathered-from-form)