# ASP.NET MVC - Controller parameter not being gathered from form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We are having this problem with a controller right now; the controller looks like this:

```
public class AccountsController:Controller {
    public ActionResult List(int? page, int? pageSize, string keywords) {...}
}
```

We are posting to this page via jquery:

```
$.post("/myapp/Accounts/List",
       {"page":0,"pageSize":10,"keywords":"asdf"}, 
       updategrid,
       "json");
...
function updategrid(result) {...}
```

Inside the action: Request.Form["keywords"] == "asdf", but keywords=="" and here I am at a loss. Why doesn't keywords have the value we want?

Comment: Using answer I provided below, but not satisfied with the resulting syntax. It just doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Comment: How is your controller being instantiated?

I had this problem and I found that it was my SpringControllerFactory creating my controllers as singletons (and hence was always using the values from the first request).

Comment: That's it! My controller was registered as a singleton into my Windsor container so my WindsorControllerFactory returned a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quoting answer provided as comment from Mark Worth...

> How is your controller being
>   instantiated? I had this problem and I
>   found that it was my
>   SpringControllerFactory creating my
>   controllers as singletons (and hence
>   was always using the values from the
>   first request). – Mark Worth May 19 at
>   8:19
>
> That's it! My controller was
>   registered as a singleton into my
>   Windsor container so my
>   WindsorControllerFactory returned a
>   singleton. – Bill Barry May 19 at
>   18:14

Answer (score 0):

Dont you want to pass the values on the URL and let the routing of MVC take care of passing the values? Not pass as actual variables?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear:

pageSize is definitely being passed in (inside the action it has the expected value of 10)
I am sending the arguments in as part of a form post. MVC does take care of moving all my values from the form into the method arguments, except for this string value.

Comment: Might want to check the routing for that particular action

Comment: the actual url rendered is ResolveUrl("~/API/Accounts/List") and the only registered route is:

    routes.MapRoute("Default", "API/{Controller}/{Action}");

Comment: could try to register a route specifically for that one to see if it comes through properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the values, you could just use a FormCollection..

```
public class AccountsController:Controller {
public ActionResult List(int? page, FormCollection collection) {

  string keywords=collection["keywords"];
  ....
}
```

}

Also, for the post, you could append the id to the url and put the other params in json. I also do not think it is necessary to put your property names in quotes in json..

```
$.post("/myapp/Accounts/List/"+page,
   {pageSize:10,keywords:"asdf"}, 
   updategrid,
   "json");
```

...
function updategrid(result) {...}

... or as others suggested, you could create a route that has all the possible parameters ..

Comment: I could, but I would like to move away from magic strings if I can. The jquery post will be generated from an expression that pretends to actually call the controller.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'magic strings' and pretending to call the controller.. could you explain?

Comment: Magic strings are strings that actually represent code, but do not get compiled (instead they are evaluated at runtime). Instead, I can "pretend" to call the action in my views in order to generate links with a command like <%=LinkToActions.RenderJQueryPostJson<AccountsController>(c=>c.List(0,10,"asdf"), "updategrid")%>
The method takes an expression tree and generates the necessary javascript into my view. Doing this, I avoid runtime errors caused by doing things like renaming parameters in the action (or for that matter adding new ones because my views will not compile).

Comment: note: I use spark for my views so that I can compile them as part of my build and it finds errors like these.

Comment: Interesting.. I hadn't seen spark before. I will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class StringParamFilterAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute {
    public string Param { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request[Param];
    }
}
```

I was able to put an attribute on the action in order to give this parameter to the method:

```
[StringParamFilter(Param="keywords")]
public ActionResult List(int? page, int? pageSize, string keywords) {...}
```

and now keywords has the desired value

Comment: Now that I have it working, the only question I have left is why is it this way (it seems that everything other than strings will be retrieved)?

Comment: I agree (I wouldn't have asked the question if it felt right).

Comment: Is it possible for you to publish your registered routes?

Comment: The actual url rendered is ResolveUrl("~/API/Accounts/List") and the only registered route is: 
routes.MapRoute("Default", "API/{Controller}/{Action}");

Answer (score 0):

Since the attribute specified above works, have you checked to compare the contents of the HttpContext.Request.Form collection against the MVC-Binder-Bound FormCollection object.?  Seems like there's a difference between the two sets.  Also, try other ways of accessing the FormCollection - Get(), GetValue() ... check AllKeys for the key you're interested in???

Also, with regards to the route-registering idea ...

If you don't have the route myApp/Accounts/List/{page}/{pageSize} registered and the pagesize is still coming through, it stands to reason that there isn't a need to register a myApp/Accounts/List/{page}/{pageSize}/{keywords} route either.

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd, because the code on my machine works.  What happens when you request the URL directly from a browser (without the jQuery .post() call) like so:

```
/myapp/Accounts/List?page=0&pageSize=10&keywords=asdf
```

That generates a GET request (instead of the POST request generated by the jQuery .post() method -- but the action method parameters should be populated nonetheless).

For the purposes of debugging, you might want to change your action method to something like:

```
public ActionResult List(int? page, int? pageSize, string keywords)
{
     return Content(String.Format("page = {0}, pageSize = {1}, keywords = {2}",
                    page, pageSize, keywords));
}
```

If that works, the next step would be to test your jQuery call with something like (changing the returned data format from JSON to text):

```
 $.post('/myapp/Accounts/List',
        { 'page' : 0, 'pageSize' : 10, 'keywords' : 'asdf' },
        function(result) {
           alert(result);
        },
        'text');
```

Everything above worked correctly for me, so unless I'm missing something... I'm puzzled why it didn't work for you?  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class JsonParametersFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string contentType = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
                return;

            if (!contentType.Contains("application/json"))
                return;

            string paramValue;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
                paramValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var rawResult = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(paramValue);

            var keys = new List<string>(filterContext.ActionParameters.Keys);

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                object value = null;

                if (rawResult.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                {
                    filterContext.ActionParameters[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will attempt to populate all parameters values from inputstream.